# Can I programatically load scenes in the Unity editor?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using the A* pathfinding algorithm for my 2D game (from my understanding, Unity Nav Meshes don't work in 2D).  I would like to be able to pre-calculate navigation grids for all of my scenes, and save them in resource files that can be loaded whenever the player enters a new scene.  Rather than having to remember to click "calculate" for every scene -- and remember to recalculate all of my scenes if I make a change to my navigation grids -- I want to be able to programatically have the Unity Editor iterate though each scene and calculate the grids.

Is there a way to create a command in the Unity editor that will iteratively open each scene in the editor and run a method on a `MonoBehaviour` that's in the scene?  Alternatively, is there another way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I'm confused so you don't want to load the scenes. All you want to do is analyze its properties progrmatically?

Comment: @Mineo333 Yeah, I just want to analyze the scenes programatically.  I mentioned loading each scene iteratively because I figured that's what I'd have to do, but if there's a way to access each scene and its components without actually loading the scene, then that'll work too.

Comment: So will this be done as soon as you run the game? Or will it be done throughout gameplay?

Comment: @Mineo333 It won't be done while the game is running.  It'll be done by me in the Unity editor prior to releasing the game.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can!

In editmode you can't use `SceneManager` but have to use the [`EditorSceneManager`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.html).

---

First of all you need the scenes you want to iterate.

Could be e.g. a `public static` field with a list of [`SceneAsset`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneAsset.html) in the Inspector where you simply reference the scenes

```c#
public static List<SceneAsset> Scenes = new List<SceneAsset>();
```

or you could get them by script e.g. for only use the scenes added to the build settings using [`EditorBuildSettings.scenes`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorBuildSettings-scenes.html)

```c#
List<EditorBuildSettingsScene> Scenes = EditorBuildSettings.scenes;
```

For both you can get a list of the scene paths e.g. using [LinQ `Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.6) (this is basically a kind of shortcut for a `foreach` loop) and [`AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath.html) like

```c#
List<string> scenePaths = Scenes.Select(scene => AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(scene)).ToList();
```

for the [EditorBuildSettingsScene](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorBuildSettingsScene.html) from `EditorBuildSettings.scenes` you can also simply use

```c#
List<string> scenePaths = Scenes.Select(scene => scene.path).ToList();
```

---

Now you can iterate over them all and do your stuff by using [`EditorSceneManager.OpenScene`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.OpenScene.html), [`EditorSceneManager.SaveScene`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.SaveScene.html) and [`EditorSceneManager.CloseScene`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.CloseScene.html) (and if you need it [AssetDatabase.SaveAssets](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.SaveAssets.html))

```c#
foreach(string scenePath in scenePaths)
{
    // Open a scene e.g. in single mode
    var currentScene = EditorSceneManager.OpenScene(scenePath);

    /* Do your calculation for currentScene */

    // Don't know if it makes changes to your scenes .. if not you can probably skip this
    EditorSceneManager.SaveScene(currentScene);

    // Finally Close and remove the scene
    EditorSceneManager.CloseScene(currentScene, true);
}

// you might be doing changes to an asset you want to save when done
AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
```

---

Before starting you should probably ask to save the current open scene(s) using [`EditorSceneManager.SaveCurrentModifiedScenesIfUserWantsTo`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.SaveCurrentModifiedScenesIfUserWantsTo.html)

```c#
if(EditorSceneManager.SaveCurrentModifiedScenesIfUserWantsTo())
{
    // Saved => the foreach loop here
}
else
{
    // aborted => do nothing
}
```

---

Than in order to finally start that method the simplest would be to add a [`[MenuItem]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MenuItem.html)

```c#
public static class Calculation
{
    [MenuItem("YourMenu/RunCalculation")]
    public static void RunCalculation()
    {
        // all the before mentioned snippets here
        // depending how exactly you want to do it
    }
}
```

This will add a new menu `YourMenu` with one entry `RunCalculation` to the top menubar of the Unity Editor.

**Note:** 
Since this uses a lot of types (`EditorSceneManager` etc) that only exist in the `UnityEditor` namespace you should either place the whole script in an `Editor` folder (so it is ignored in the final build) or use pre-processors like

```c#
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    // ... code here
#endif
```

so in the build the code is also ignored.

---

Note that I'm assuming so far you also did your calculation in editmode. The thing is if this calculation relies somewhere aon any `Start` or `Awake` method you have to call it manually from that editorscript before running the calculation.

Comment: Excellent answer!  Thanks for taking the time to write all that out.

Comment: You're welcome! I hacked this in on my phone so I'm glad it worked for you ;)

Comment: Any way to just get all scene assets in the project? (regardless of build settings?)

Comment: @AdamKeenan [`Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<SceneAsset>()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll.html) should do that trick.